# Execute action when an animation is repeated in Android

Tags: android, animation, repeat

I'm trying stuff with android animation and I would like to know if there is a way to execute some code every time an animation is repeated? I looked at the google doc but didn"t find any method to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html), overriding `onAnimationRepeat()`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tip Mr Murphy. As always we can count on you!!